# Path to controller method in external js (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have ASP.NET MVC app.

In this app I have script, that I want to move to external file and faced issue

Here is code

```
    function todolisttoday() {
    $("#list").empty();
    $("#counter").empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetTodayList", "Home")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var list = data;
            var count = Object.keys(data).length;
            $("#counter").append('<b>' + "You have" + " " + count + " " + "appointments today" + '</b>');
            for (var i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {
                var timeobject = new Date();
                timeobject.setTime(Date.parse(list[i].time));
                var hours = timeobject.getHours();
                var minutes = timeobject.getMinutes();
                var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
                hours = hours % 12;
                hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
                minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
                var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
                var divslist = '<div class="listdiv">' +
                    '<b >' + (i + 1) + '</b>' + "." + " "
                    + '<b class="title">' + list[i].title + '</b>' + " "
                    + '<b >' + strTime + '</b>' + '<b class="status" style="display:none;">' + list[i].status + '<b>'
                    + '</div>';
                $("#list").append(divslist);
            };
        }
    });
};
```

So, as I know this row `url: '@Url.Action("GetTodayList", "Home")'` won't work.

If it function will be calling via button I can use this `data-request-url="@Url.Action("GetTodayList", "Home")"`

But function is called on page load in `$(document).ready`

How I can make url path to be valid?

Comment: `$(document).ready()` means the html has been loaded, so you can use a `data-*` attribute in your button. But why are you doing this instead of sending the data in your model (and as a side note, your `contentType`, `data` and `processData` options are pointless and can be removed)

Comment: I don't use button. I call function after load, so I cannot use data-request-url@StephenMuecke

Comment: You can put that in any element and access using `var url = $(yourElement).data('request-url');` But again, why are you doing this (its crazy to send a request to your server, return a response but then _sorry, I forgot to send your the information, so waste some more time making another request to get it_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

js file can't compile as cshtml so `@Url.Action("GetTodayList", "Home")` can't be used in JS.

you can set this rl manual like `/home/GetTodayList` in JS or

```
var jsModule = function (urls) {
    .
    .
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: urls.GetTodayList,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {

        });
    })
}
```

in view

```
 <script src="..."></script>
 <script>
    var urls={GetTodayList:'@Url.Action("GetTodayList", "Home")'}
    jsModule(urls);
 </script>
```